# Display events from database into angularjs mwl calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display all the events from a database into mwl calender based on the date.But right now all the events are being displayed for today's date.How to display events based on date saved in database.?

**html**

```
    <mwl-calendar
    events="events"
    view="calendarView"
    current-day="viewDate"
    view-title="calendarTitle"
    ng-model="eventSources"
    cell-is-open="cellIsOpen"
    day-view-start="06:00"
    day-view-end="22:59"
    day-view-split="30"
    cell-modifier="modifyCell(calendarCell)"
    cell-auto-open-disabled="true"
    on-timespan-click="timespanClicked(calendarDate)">
    </mwl-calendar>
```

**controller**

```
    $scope.myevents = function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    SalesNotifyService.getAllNotify().success(function(data) {
    $scope.events = [];
    angular.forEach(data,function(event,key){
    $scope.events.push({
      employeeName: event.employeeName,
      notifyDate: event.notifyDate,
      });
      });
      callback($scope.events);
      });
      }
      $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events,$scope.myevents];
```

I want to display events based on notifyDate.If the notifyDate is 12-12-2020 then in the calendar for 12-12-2020 it should display employeeName related to that notifyDate.Can anyone tell how to display events based on notifyDate from the database?

Comment: do you want to order the events by notifyDate?
If yes you can either order them on server side with sql or use lodash in your angular app

Comment: I just want to display events based on notifyDate.For example if notifyDate is 12-12-2019 in my calendar for 12-12-2019 it should display employeeName

Comment: according to the official documentation every event object needs a title, color and startAt property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every event object needs the following properties:

- title
- startsAt
- color

Try to build your objects with those properties

```
SalesNotifyService.getAllNotify().success(function(data) {
    $scope.events = [];
    angular.forEach(data,function(event,key){
        $scope.events.push({
            title: event.employeeName,
            startsAt: event.notifyDate, // needs to be a javascript date object
            color: {
                primary: '#e3bc08',
                secondary: '#fdf1ba'
            },
        });
    });
}
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar).

Comment: Ok i have one more doubt.Do i need to call ng-init for calling $scope.myevents?

Comment: events just needs to be an array, doesn't matter if it is empty or not. So you could initialize $scope.events with an empty array

Comment: No.I asked do i need to give ng-init for calling function $scope.myevents? inside my html.If i give also it is giving callback is not a function error

Comment: The events are not getting displayed for particular notifyDate.It is displaying all events for todays date

Comment: That is probably because startsAt needs to be a JavaScript Date object.
You need to parse event.notifyDate to a Date object.
I'm not sure where and why you are using $scope.myevents have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: yeah i parsed it like this startAt: new Date(event.notifyDate).But still not displaying

Comment: In console i am getting like this {title: "John", startAt: Thu Jan 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), color: {…}}

Comment: try to use startsAt instead of startAt

Comment: Hope I helped :) Please make sure to accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: yeah sure bro:)

Comment: Can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384776/including-custom-template-urls-inside-mwl-calendar-angularjs..It is a similar question.I want to customize calendar.But customTemplateUrl is not working